# Sequelize Model Loader not detecting model methods

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, typescript-typings, sequelize-typescript

I'm trying to get sequelize to work with TypeScript and I currently have this model loader that works as expected

```
import { Account, initAccount } from "./account";
import { initOrder, Order } from "./order";
import { initPrice, Price } from "./price";

import {Sequelize, Model} from 'sequelize';

const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(`${__dirname}/../../config/config.json`)[env];

interface db {
    Order: Order;
    Account: Account;
    Candle: Candle;
}

const sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);

initAccount(sequelize);
initOrder(sequelize);
initPrice(sequelize);

const db = {
    sequelize,
    Sequelize,
    Account: Account,
    Order: Order,
    Price: Price,
}

export default db;
```

And I have imported this into another file by doing `import db from './models'` but if I start typing `db.Order.` I should get a list of all available sequelize methods but I do not.

I can import the individual models by using `import {Price} from './models/price';` for example, and that works correctly. Although that defeats the purpose of using a single model loader.

How can I change my model loader to allow it to show all the methods I can run from a single function?

Below is an example of my model definitions

```
import {
    Sequelize,
    Model,
    DataTypes,
    Optional,
} from "sequelize";

interface AccountAttributes {
    id?: number;
    accountId: string;
    currency: string;
    balance: number;
}

interface AccountCreationAttributes extends Optional<AccountAttributes, "id"> { }

export class Account extends Model<AccountAttributes, AccountCreationAttributes> implements AccountAttributes {
    public id!: number;
    public accountId!: string;
    public currency!: string;
    public balance!: number;
    
    // timestamps!
    public readonly createdAt!: Date;
    public readonly updatedAt!: Date;

}

export function initAccount(sequelize: Sequelize): void {
    Account.init({
        accountId: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        currency: DataTypes.STRING,
        balance: DataTypes.INTEGER
    }, {
        tableName: 'accounts',
        sequelize: sequelize,
    });
}
```

**Update**

So now the different model methods are detected but if I try to access a property of a model I get this error `Property 'currency' does not exist on type 'Model<any, any>'.`

The code I use to try to access the `currency` property is below

```
let accountCurrencies: Array<number> = [];
const accounts = await db.Account.findAll({
    limit: 50,
});

for (let i = 0; i < accounts .length; i++) {
    accountCurrencies.push(accounts[i].currency);
}
```

Comment: show model definitions. And at least you should change `any` to something common to all your models like the base class Model from Sequelize

Comment: @Anatoly I have updated my post to show model definitions

Comment: Did you try `interface db {
    [key: string]: Model;
}`?

Comment: That creates some other issues if I try that, for example `Type 'Model<any, any>' has no call signatures` on one of my `findAll` methods

Comment: I see. Unfortunately there is no common type for all registered models

Comment: So would I have to make a type for each model? If so how would I do that

Comment: You should define model classes like this `class Project extends Model<ProjectAttributes, ProjectCreationAttributes>
  implements ProjectAttributes`, see https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html. Then you should use these classes as types for concrete keys in `db` object

Comment: @Anatoly I've updated my post with a new model definition but its still not seeming to work

Comment: Sorry I meant to use types in `interface db`

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: `interface db {
    Order: Order;
    Account: Account;
    Price: Price;
}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225228/discussion-between-hcphoon-and-anatoly).